# Spring OAuth2: Access token denied because client_id not specified

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, intercom

I am trying to implement Intercom OAuth2 in my spring application. I am running into a strange problem.

Once the user gives the app permission to use its data a POST request is sent to the access token uri (`https://api.intercom.io/auth/eagle/token`). This post request is handled by spring.

But then I get the error that

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Access token denied.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:142) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:143) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:119) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception: OAuth Error
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:119) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:33) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2913) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:235) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
04:39:57.150 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] D
```

Upon debugging I found that the POST request is failing due to the absence of client_id. This is a part of the json I receive.

```
"errors":[{"code":"parameter_not_found","message":"client_id not specified"}
```

My `oauth.properties` file contains both the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

```
intercom.client.clientId=MY_CLIENT_ID
intercom.client.clientSecret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET
intercom.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://app.intercom.io/oauth
intercom.client.accessTokenUri=https://api.intercom.io/auth/eagle/token
```

But when I do the same for other oauth providers like `github`, `google` etc it works fine. I even tried the POST request via curl with the `client_id` and `client_secret` and the request was successful and I got the token. I am not able to understand why spring is causing an error here. While it works perfectly for other oauth providers.

Can anyone help me. Why might this be happening? I can't seem to find the issue. Thanks !!

Comment: Maybe you have to inject your properties using xml or annotation the spring can get client information. You also refer to the post oauth2 http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-example.html